# Blogger headings conditions on Index and Item pages

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, blogger

On Blogger I have a `<class="subheading">` which I have applied to all `<h2>` on the item page, however on the index page, I need the `<class="subheading">` to be for `<h3>`.

This is the codes I'm using but it doesn't work

code 1

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'> 
 <h3 class='subtitle' itemprop='name'></h3>
<b:else/> 
 <h2 class='subtitle' itemprop='name'></h2> 
</b:if>
```

code 2

```
<b:if cond='data:post.body'> 
 <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'> 
  <h3 class='subtitle' itemprop='name'></h3>
 <b:else/> 
  <h2 class='subtitle' itemprop='name'></h2> 
 </b:if> 
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your code in `<b:if cond='data:post.body'>`. It will executed only on the Individual Posts.This should help you.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
    <!-- Individual Post -->
  <h3 class='subtitle' itemprop='name'>h3 test</h3>
<b:else/> 
  <!-- other pages -->
   <h2 class='subtitle' itemprop='name'>h2 test</h2>
</b:if>
```

Check different types of pages and [if else conditions for Blogger](http://monkeyraptor.johanpaul.net/2013/06/blogger-conditional-tag-bif-and-belse.html).

**Update:**
Blogger is not really that customizable and you might need to use jQuery tweaks to accomplish the goal. There can be multiple solutions to your problem depending what do u want to show on home page and other pages.

Have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/imsangram/e7okmjq7/) code.

Basically, the text which is to be shown in h2 and h3 can be kept in hidden span at the end of page. On Page load you can programmatically find it and assign in h2 or h3 depending on your requirements. Also, if you are new in jQuery, have a look at the code used in existing blogger templates.

Comment: Thank you, but this makes the subheading 'h3 test' appear on each post subheading, however I need each subheading to have it's own name in each individual post, not to be overrode with 'h3 test'. Is there a way around this?

Comment: H3 Test is just an example. I believe u wish to add some common text across your blog. What do you want to put in class='subtitle'? also. give us the link to blog so we can understand the requirement and help you in better manner.

Comment: It won't be a common text, each will be different depending on the post.

Comment: I believe you have some text which will change on every page and you wish to append that into h2/h3? Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes this is right, so for example if there's a post about cars the subtitle will be `<h2 class="subtitle">Mini</h2>` on the item page, but I need this to change to `<h3>` on the index page. Each subtitle will be different on every page.